# Create a generic method Print which will accept all type of collections to It

Tags: java, generics, collections, compiler-errors, hashmap

Why the print method for map is not working?
the method should accept all generics and print them.
it works fine for list, set, Queues but problem arises in map.

```
public class Question6 {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static void print(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Collection c) {
        System.out.println(c.getClass());
        c.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        print(l);
            
        List<Dummy> ld = new ArrayList<Dummy>();
        ld.add(new Dummy());
        print(ld);

        Map<Integer,Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        m.put(1,1);
        print(m); // gives error?
                
    }
}

class Dummy{
    
}
```

Comment: `Map` is not a collection.

Comment: Also your `print` method is unnecessary.  Just use `System.out.print()`, it works fine.

Comment: for printing the class content you could just call the `toString()` method on bot the collection or map and it will print you the content.

Comment: Use `Collection<?>` instead of a raw type. Since `Map` is not a collection, you have to decide. You can pass `m.entrySet()` to the method. Or use `keySet()` or `values()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` is not a `Collection`. You can either call your `print` method like this:

```
print(map.entrySet());
// or 
print(map.keys());
// or
print(map.values());
```

or **overload** it as follows:

```
static void print(Collection<?> c) {
    System.out.println(c.getClass());
    c.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
}

static void print(Map<?, ?> map) {
    System.out.println(map.getClass());
    map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
}
```